# Returning ID of the table for corresponding aggregate result

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, min

I have a table like this:

```
+-----+------------+-------+--------+
| ID  |  val1      | val2  | val3   |
+-----+------------+-------+--------+
| 100 |  110       | 25    | 530    |
| 101 |  56        | 75    | 591    |
| 102 |  65        | 93    | 827    |
| 103 |  75        | 70    | 805    |
+-----+------------+-------+--------+
```

I want to write a query in postgreSQL that whenever *(val3-val1)* is minimum, returns the *ID* for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `order by`:

```
select  id
from    YourTable
order by
        val3 - val1
limit   1
```

Comment: Andomar, I'm curious, what's the performance of this (`ORDER BY val3 - val1`), as opposed to ordering by the two columns themselves (say, `ORDER BY val3 ASC, val1 DESC`)?  Of course, I guess you'd need an index for that to work any better, really, but would the optimizer be smart enough to be able to use it?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: you can't order by the columns themselves, that would return the wrong result.

Comment: Ack, noo, you're right.  #headdesk#  Didn't think that completely through (for cases where `val1` may be greatly larger than `val3`, which could be large itself).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want correctly, this can be phrased in SQL pretty close to how you wrote it literally in words.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/61046/1

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
WHERE (val1 - val3) = (SELECT min(val1-val3) FROM Table1);
```

This will return multiple results if multiple rows have the same `val1 - val3`. You would need to add additional criteria if that's a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT  t1.ID
FROM Tablename t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT Id, MIN(val3 - val1) Minval
   FROM Tablename
   GROUP BY Id
) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.Id AND t2.minval = (t1.val3 - t1.val1)
```

Comment: If `Id` is a unique column as it seems, `group by Id` won't accomplish much?